# What is this operator doing &= in this code?? (c#)

Tags: c#

In the code below, what is the value of x and why?

```
bool x =true;
x &= false;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

x is false, becase (true & false) == false.

&= is to & as += is to +.

Comment: So the question becomes... why use &= at all and not just x=false; ?

Comment: so '&=' is a shortcut for 'x = (x & false)' ?

Answer (score 12):

```
x &= false;
```

is shorthand for:

```
x = x & false;
```

so in your code: true & false resolves to false.

Answer (score 2):

```
x &= false;
```

is the same as

```
x = x & false;
```

So, as moonshadow says: false...

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c(VS.80).aspx)

Excerpt: Binary & operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, & computes the logical bitwise AND of its operands. For bool operands, & computes the logical AND of its operands; that is, the result is true if and only if both its operands are true.

So in other words this is saying that x is false in your example because (true and false) is false

Answer (score 1):

&= is the AND assignment operator [(see this MSDN page)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02(VS.80).aspx).

It's the same idea as += which you can read as:

'Perform the + operation on the variable and then assign it back to itself'

Answer (score 1):

```
x &= false
```

is just a short form of

```
x = x & false
```

x will be false at the end of that code.

&= is an assignment operater there are a bunch of them(+=, -=, *=, /=, |= and more).  They are just short ways to perform an operation on a variable and assign the result back to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

The & operator is a logical "and" that always evaluates both halves of the expression. Unless both operands are true, & returns false. x &= y is shorthand for x = x & y.

Far more common in C# usage is the && operator, which returns the same value, but stops evaluating operands once a false value is found. This has to do with the side effects of functions that return values. For example:

```
if(ConnectToDatabase() && ExecuteQuery())
```

will run ConnectToDatabase() in all cases, but only run ExecuteQuery if ConnectToDatabase() returns true. In this case, you don't want to try to run a query if the database is not connected.

On the other hand:

```
if(VerifyIdentity() & RegisterRequest())
```

will always execute VerifyIdentity() and RegisterRequest(), then evaluate the truthiness of their combined return values.

Answer (score 1):

This operator can be used with validation...

```
valid = True;
valid &= firstname.isValid();
valid &= lastname.isValid();
valid &= email.isValid();

if(valid)
   // do something;
```